# Gnome shell and windown cycling by repeatedly typing ALT-TAB (kind of) broken (17.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04, gnome-shell

When I press the ALT-TAB combination, i get the default window switcher, but repeatedly typing ALT-TAB should cycle the windows. Instead, it keeps focused on the current window. I can still switch to another window by pointing with the mouse.

The application window switcher (2nd level switcher to cycle through the open windows of an application) still works as expected, though.

Is there a way to diagnose what is going on, or to reset this functionality?

By the way, if I install the coverflow switcher extension, the function works as expected. I just would prefer the default switcher.

**UPDATE:**
Super-TAB also invokes the switcher, and has the expected behavior, but how is it that ALT-TAB also calls the switcher, with the broken window cycling behavior?

Comment: I found this that may help: http://wiredrevolution.com/gnome/fix-alt-tab-task-switching-in-gnome-shell

But it didn't work for me because I can't open gconf-editor. It says command not found. How can I get into the gconf-editor?

Comment: Have you tried  `sudo apt install gconf-editor` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. After installing it I could use gconf-editor. However, nothing helped. My Alt-Tab is still broken.